# android apk runtime error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I  have an app that I put in package/app/myappfolder, I use a library android-support-v4.jar from google, and it is in myappfolder/libs, in Android.mk file I add below lines:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-support-v4
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-support-v4:libs/android-support-v4.jar
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false
```

and  my code has using android.support.v4.app.* package.

then, I build using "mmm -b packages/app/myappfolder", it gives out build message, it contains below lines

```
Install: out/target/product/target/system/app/myapp.apk
target Prebuilt: android-support-v4 (out/target/product/target/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v4_intermediates/javalib.jar)
```

I thought,  it means that build has generated myapp.apk and javalib.jar, the javalib.jar has the library the same as android-support-v4.jar, right?

I just know adb install -r myapp.apk to my target board, and the app can't run, and crashs with errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(24403): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020000 a=-1 r=0x7f020000}
E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1927)
E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:431)
E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:101)
E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
E/AndroidRuntime(24403):    ... 28 more
E/AndroidRuntime(24422): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(24422): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.changhong.factorymode/com.changhong.factorymode.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

And this app is run well if using eclipse with ADT build and install, Is it the reason that I don't push the javalib.jar to my target board?  if so, how to do this? and has any other reason?

Comment: Can you show the source where it is crashing?

Comment: the source is ok, I think,  I replace all android.support.v4.app.*,  and it works fine. So,  is it the library issue that library path is not right? In android source  which location the library is under rather than app locale folder?